# Has_many :through in Rails 3 - with an extra ID to be set in the joining model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model, sqlite

I have put together a diagram to help explain the issue: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YP9P1.png

Basically, on my "New Employee" form, I currently have a input field for employee name, and a select box that lists all companies. If I select a company and hit go, it creates a new record in "employment". So far, so good.

My issue is that when selecting a company, it also needs to set the type in the "employment" model, which links to the "employment type" model. Ideally, so that I can have 2 different types of employment - but both list the same companies.

Thanks in advance, any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure I complete understand your question, but I'll take a shot at it.

Employee Model:

```
has_many :employments, :dependent => :destroy
has_many :companies; :through=>employments
has_many :employment_types, :through=>employments
```

Company Model:

```
has_many :employments
has_many :employees; :through=>employments
has_many :employment_types, :through=>employments
```

Employment Type Model:

```
has_many :employments
has_many :companies; :through=>employments
has_many :employees; :through=>employments
```

Employment Model:

```
belongs_to :employee
belongs_to :company
belongs_to :employment_type
```

View code:

```
<%= form_for @employee do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <% 2.times do %>
    <%= f.fields_for :employments, @employee.employments.build do |employment_fields| %>
      <%= f.select :company_id, options_from_collection_for_select(Company.all, 'id', 'name') %>
      <%= f.select :employment_type_id, options_from_collection_for_select(EmploymentType.all, 'id', 'name') %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

In your diagram you have the ID fields as non standard (model_id), rails typically prefers these to just be id.  But you can over ride the default primary key by adding this to each model:

```
set_primary_key <symbol representing primary key>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've setup my relationships as you've described as it's mostly working - although when I submit the form, it's creating 2 new records inside of "Employment" instead of 1. One has both Employee ID and Company ID, the other has Employee ID and Employment Type ID. Is there a way to keep these 3 together in the same new record?

Comment: Can you post the code to your create method as well as a copy of the params hash from the request?

Comment: I haven't changed the default create method:

Comment: What default create method?  Did you use a scaffold or something to create your controller?

Comment: Yes, my apologies - the default create method that scaffold generates: https://gist.github.com/2360902

Comment: It appears you have something weird in your view.  Can you post your form.  We should be able to change the params from employee"=>{"name"=>"David Smith", "company_ids"=>["", "3"], "company_type_ids"=>["", "1"]} to employee"=>{"name"=>"David Smith", "employments"=> [{"company_ids"=>"", "company_type_ids"=>""}, ...]}

Comment: Thanks, really appreciate the help. For my form, I'm using the gem formtastic to simplify it. Also, the current layout is 2 select boxes (one for company, one for company type) - what I would really like it two for companies, but one for company type 1, the other for company type 2. The 'Remove' links are also a WIP, but that's not an issue. Gist: https://gist.github.com/2360982

Comment: I updated the answer to allow you two have to employments, in one form.  You may need to adjust for your exact code, but that will work with the models I defined earlier.

Comment: I've set it up as you've shown - but getting an undefined method error - undefined method `employment'. On line 4. I must be missing something for the relationship between employee and employment, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: that should have been employments.build

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9975/discussion-between-ben-miller-and-kobius)